# Localisation of Azure AD B2C custom policy showing unicode characters instead actual letter

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to implement localisation in custom policies and created localised resources:

```xml
    <LocalizedResources Id="signin_es">
                    <LocalizedStrings>
                        <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="button_continue">INICIAR SESIÓN</LocalizedString>
                        <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="signInName" StringId="DisplayName">Correo electrónico o número de teléfono</LocalizedString>
                        <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="password" StringId="DisplayName">Contrasena</LocalizedString>
                        <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="password" StringId="UserHelpText">Introducir la contraseña</LocalizedString>
                    </LocalizedStrings>
                </LocalizedResources>
```

When it is renders in browser, for `"Correo electrónico o número de teléfono"` it is showing `"Correo electr&#243;nico o n&#250;mero de tel&#233;fono"`

The data uri i'm using is `urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.0.0` and using my own html page. I can add one more thing, the unicode charecters are showing only for labels, placeholder of the text box is perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the prior version of DATAURI `urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:1.2.0`

This worked, so i think this is the issue of version 2.0.0.

Comment: I think this is still a bug. I'm using version 2.1.0 and it doesn't work